# Non-Paginated, Dynamic Adding Search Results

Tags: solspace, supersearch, dynamic

I have been asked to set up a "show more" search results expansion instead of "next page" style. An example would be, when you are reading comments on LinkedIn, instead of a list of pages of comments you can review, you simply click "show more" and it dynamically loads additional comments.

I purchased Solspace Super Search this morning, as the built in search was too limited for our needs. I'm curious if anyone has created something like this already, and would have suggestions. Alternately, if no one has done this, any suggestions on where I might start? (*long* time programmer, PHP and many more, don't hold back if you think i might not understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 ways to approach this I know of are:

1 - grab all the results with super search and hide the extra, using js to reveal the extras as needed

2 - grab only a portion of the results with super search, then as needed use ajax to get additional results from a second template (maybe a template formatting the results as json).

Whether I would use 1 or 2 would depend on how many entries you expect to show, seo concerns, and how much time you want to spend(!).

Comment: Finally got back around to this project. #2 worked just fine. I had to tweak a few bits with expression engine routes and jquery to make it work smoothly, but works like a dream now. :)